# Can we have multiple dynamic links point to single app?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native-ios, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to know whether we can have multiple dynamic links to point to my react native ios app.

Say, I am using ab2ya.app.goo.gl/ already registered with my app, and I also have apple-site-association file setup aswell.

Now, for marketing purposes I would like to have another format of the dynamic link that looks more professional, like appname.page.link/.

But in xcode I can only setup one firebase url. How to use both the formats at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple domain entitlements to your apps: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/setting_up_an_app_s_associated_domains

As long as both your app and the firebase console are aware of a domain, dynamic links should work!